# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked error when assigning to random color in array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I want to assign to a random color of the array. It actually first works but then I get an error message: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked" I even see how it one second before the message come the color of the chip change very fast. So it somehiw works... How can I fix this issue. (I also added the code and funcs for the createion of the chips) I know that I first have to initialize it. But I dont know how to accomplish that, so it would be nice if you could write directly in my code. I have been trying many things, but nothing worked.

HTML

```
<ion-chip [color]="color[getRandomInt(color.length)]" class="chip" #chip *ngFor="let tag of tagName">
```

TS

```
export class Tag {
  color = ["ok", "nice","awesome","danger","white"];
  colorSelected = null;
  tag: string;
  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.colorSelected = this.color[this.getRandomInt(this.color.length)];
  }
}

...

  color: string [] = ["ok", "nice","awesome","danger","white"]



  tagName: Tag[] = [];

...

add(): void {
  let id = this.tagName.length + 1;
  this.tagName.push(new Tag({ tag: "tag" + id }, ));
}

remove(tag: Tag) {
  let id = this.tagName.indexOf(tag);
  this.tagName.splice(id, 1);
}



getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `console.log` in `getRandomInt` method you will see it is called **many many times** which is not good.

Instead I would suggest to assign the color to your object once, (you need to add `color` to your `Tag` class as well)

something like this

```
add(): void {
  let id = this.tagName.length + 1;
  this.tagName.push(new Tag({ tag: "tag" + id, color: this.color[this.getRandomInt(this.color.length)] }, ));
}
```

then in html it will be like

```
<ion-chip [color]="tag.color" class="chip" #chip *ngFor="let tag of tagName">
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is ensure you're only setting the color once, so you need to move the method call out of the template. Instead, you should do:

```
this.tagName = this.tagName.map((tag) => tag.color =  this.color[this.getRandomInt(this.color.length)]);
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<ion-chip [color]="tag.color"
```